# How to change redirect URL of Cancel button

Tags: sharepoint-designer, custom-form

I'm creating a custom 'NewForm.aspx' and am looking to customize the 'cancel' button action.

Preferrably I would like it to 'go back' a step, else to go to a hardcoded URL.

I have tried this solution by adding the following code -

`<input type="button" value="Close" name="gobackbutton2" onclick="javascript: {ddwrt:GenFireServerEvent('__commit;__redirect={/Lists/History/AllItems.aspx}')}" />`

But when the person clicks on the 'Close' button, it still requires the user to fill out the required fields. 
How can that be avoided, and/or how can I trigger a 'back' action?

Using SharePoint 2013 Designer

Comment: Any possible ideas? :)

Comment: 'Why are you committing? You can simply drop the commit and now it should redirect away with no problem. On commit it preforms a check on the form (hence forcing users to enter in data)

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried [this](http://www.sharepointbriefing.com/spcode/article.php/3865791/Take-Control-of-Your-OK-and-Cancel-Buttons.htm)?

TL;DR version, using jQuery:

```
$(function() {
  $('input[value=Cancel]').click(function() {history.go(-1);});
});
```

Or to tackle both Cancel buttons at once:

```
function redirectCancelButtons(){
    // form Cancel button
    jQuery('input[value=Cancel]').click(function() {history.go(-1);});

    // ribbon Cancel button
    jQuery('#Ribbon.ListForm.Edit.Commit.Cancel-Large').click(function(){history.go(-1);});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use RedirectUrl="your url" like:

```
<SharePoint:GoBackButton runat="server" ControlMode="New" id="gobackbutton1" RedirectUrl="URL"/>
```

Comment: Can you provide some information on RedirectUrl?  It'd help other people reading your answer to understand it.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @Drale, there is the possibility to overwrite the standard redirect url using the `RedirectUrl` attribute. There is no really documentation regarding it, but the [class definition](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.gobackbutton?view=sharepoint-server) may help.

This is my solution (redirecting to the `DispForm`):

```
<SharePoint:GoBackButton runat="server" ControlMode="Edit" id="gobackbutton2" RedirectUrl="DispForm.aspx?ID={$ListItemId}"/>
```

In order to have the `ListItemId` defined it must be specified at the beginning of the stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:x="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    xmlns:dsp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/dsp" version="1.0" exclude-result-prefixes="xsl msxsl ddwrt" xmlns:ddwrt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/runtime" xmlns:asp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ASPNET/20" xmlns:__designer="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/designer" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:SharePoint="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" xmlns:ddwrt2="urn:frontpage:internal">
    <xsl:param name="ListItemId"></xsl:param> // <-- do not forget!

    // custom definition of the form

</stylesheet>
```

Furthermore, this is possible also with the `SaveButton` ([MS page](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.savebutton?view=sharepoint-server)):

```
<SharePoint:SaveButton runat="server" ControlMode="Edit" id="savebutton2" RedirectUrl="DispForm.aspx?ID={$ListItemId}"/>
```

IMHO I don't know why this works, since the item does not exists yet snd so ListItemId should be null.

*EDIT:*
**Warning!** This method has a problem. When the item is deleted, the system tries to lookup the item, obiously it can't found and the user get to an error page.

Furthermore, lets take this example:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="ms-descriptiontext" nowrap="nowrap">
            <SharePoint:CreatedModifiedInfo ControlMode="Edit" runat="server"/>
        </td>
        <td class="ms-toolbar" nowrap="nowrap">
            <SharePoint:SaveButton runat="server" ControlMode="Edit" id="savebutton2" RedirectUrl="DispForm.aspx?ID={$ListItemId}"/>
        </td>
        <td class="ms-toolbar" nowrap="nowrap">
            <SharePoint:GoBackButton runat="server" ControlMode="Edit" id="gobackbutton2" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

In this case the attribute `RedirectUrl="DispForm.aspx?ID={$ListItemId}"` affects also the `GoBackButton`...